# Why chrome api "chrome.usb.findDevices" is inconsistent with previous api?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, usb-drive

I used chrome api to communicate with usb devices and found that I can successfully open the device but cannot receive data from device(Given that the vendorId and productId are right and the device truly sent data to computers).

My code is like this:

```
chrome.usb.findDevices(handle,
      function(devices) {
        if (!devices || !devices.length) {
          console.log('device not found');
          return;
        }
        var device = devices[0];
        chrome.usb.interruptTransfer(device, transfer, onEvent);
});
var onEvent = function(event) {
   if (event && event.resultCode === 0 && event.data) {
      console.log("got " + event.data.byteLength + " bytes");
   }
   chrome.usb.interruptTransfer(powerMateDevice, transfer, onEvent);

}
```

I just wonder that whether the api messed up. Here is the doc of chrome api:

> chrome.usb.interruptTransfer(connectionHandle, transferInfo, transferCallback);
>
> transferCallback   Invoked when the transfer has completed. **Notice that this >callback doesn't contain the device's response. The purpose of the callback is simply to >notify your code that the asynchronous transfer requests has been processed.**

It said "Notice that this callback doesn't contain the device's response". I remember the previous api "chrome.usb.findDevice" instead of "chrome.usb.findDevices" did support onEvent function to continuously accept usb data.

Anyone can give me clue to solve this issue?